# Python String and Instance Object confusion

Tags: python, string, instance

Inside a class, in the `__repr__` constructor, python is confused about what is a string and what isn't. This is for a school project, don't worry, I won't actually be handling social security numbers here.

The code below does not work:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return (
        '\nName:\t'+self.getName()+':\t\t\tNurse\n'+
        '\tPhone:\t\t\t\t\t\t('+str(self.getPhoneNumber())[0:3]+') '+
        str(self.getPhoneNumber())[3:6]+'-'+str(self.getPhoneNumber())[6:10]+'\n'+
        '\tOverseeing Doctor:\t\t\t'+self.getDoctor()+'\n'
        '\tDescription:\t\t\t\t'+self.getDesc()+'\n'+
        '\tBirthday:\t\t\t\t\t'+self.getBDay()+'\n'+
        '\tSocial Security Number:\t\t***-**-'+str(round(self.getSocial()))[5:9]+'\n'+#error is in this line
        str(self._cases[i] for i in range(len(self._cases)))
    )
```

However, in a different class, I have nearly identical code that does work:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return (
        '\nName:\t'+self.getName()+':\t\t\tDoctor\n'+
        '\tPhone:\t\t\t\t\t\t('+str(self.getPhoneNumber())[0:3]+') '+
        str(self.getPhoneNumber())[3:6]+'-'+str(self.getPhoneNumber())[6:10]+'\n'+
        '\tDepartment:\t\t\t\t\t'+self.getDepartment()+'\n'
        '\tDescription:\t\t\t\t'+self.getDesc()+'\n'+
        '\tBirthday:\t\t\t\t\t'+self.getBDay()+'\n'+
        '\tSocial Security Number:\t\t***-**-'+str(self.getSocial())[5:9]+'\n'+
        str(self._cases)+'\n'
    )
```

Please tell me what is different between the two, and how to fix the initial code.

Comment: So *how* does the code not work? What goes wrong and what did you expect instead?

Comment: You should strongly consider using `str.format` instead of that. If you want debugging help, more detail than *"does not work"* would be appreciated, and a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that *actually runs* is a must.

Comment: Well, the first difference I can see is that the first one says `Nurse` and the second one says `Doctor`. I guess you fix the initial code by paying for the Nurse to go to med school?

Comment: Is an exception thrown? If so, please provide the error trace. Does the program terminate, but with unexpected result? If so, please provide expected and actual result.

Comment: Also, it's highly unlikely that Python is confused about what is a string and what isn't. If you can tell us why you _think_ it's confused, we can probably tell you why _you're_ confused.

Comment: Can you give us `print repr(self.getSocial())` and `print round` (yes, no call, just the function)?

Comment: @abarnert that's a great way to irritate nurses...

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Well, if anyone knows how to treat minor irritation, it's nurses. :)

Answer (score 1):

You claim there is an error in this part:

```
str(round(self.getSocial()))[5:9]
```

but did not tell us anything about your actual error; errors come with *tracebacks and exception messages*, but without those details we cannot tell you anything about what might go wrong there. Perhaps `self.getSocial()` returns a string, and `round()` only takes *floating point numbers*:

```
>>> round('123')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

You'll need to give us that error message as well as your inputs (the return value of `self.getSocial()`) and the expected output so we can help you solve that part; perhaps you misunderstood what `round()` does.

Next, you are trying to convert a *generator expression* to a string:

```
str(self._cases[i] for i in range(len(self._cases))
```

Everything between the parentheses is a *lazy evaluating loop*, but `str()` won't evaluate it for you.

If you wanted to produce a string of all cases, joined together with, say, tabs, use `str.join()` instead:

```
'\t'.join([str(self._cases[i]) for i in range(len(self._cases)])
```

You really should look into using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) templating; it'll make for *much* improved and readable code. Your 'working' example would translate to:

```
def __repr__(self):
    phone = str(self.getPhoneNumber())
    social = str(self.getSocial())
    return (
        '\n'
        'Name:\t{name}:\t\t\tDoctor\n'
        '\tPhone:\t\t\t\t\t\t({phone1}) {phone2}-{phone3}\n'
        '\tDepartment:\t\t\t\t\t{dept}\n'
        '\tDescription:\t\t\t\t{desc}\n'
        '\tBirthday:\t\t\t\t\t{bday}\n'
        '\tSocial Security Number:\t\t***-**-{social}\n'
        '{cases}\n').format(
            name=self.getName(), 
            phone1=phone[:3], phone2=phone[3:6], phone3=phone[6:10],
            dept=self.getDepartment(), desc=self.getDesc(),
            bday=self.getBDay(), social=social[5:9],
            cases=self._cases)
```

Comment: Good catch. But that mistake should give him a string with something like `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x106071e10>` in the middle of it somewhere, which doesn't sound like Python being "confused about what is a string and what isn't"; he's still getting a string, not raising any exceptions, etc.?

Comment: It's also worth nothing that `self._cases[i] for i in range(len(self._cases))` is effectively a really verbose way to write `iter(self._cases)`, so it's probably not what he wanted in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert: yet that is the only real difference in the two strings that I can see.

Comment: @abarnert: ah, there is also a `round()` function call in there; not sure what they are trying to do with *that*.

Comment: And the `round` is on a social security number?! Yeah, that could be it.

Comment: @abarnert: the OP added a `#error is in this line` after the social security number part, hidden by the scroll. I missed it the first time around.